# What happens when SIGCANCEL is sent to a thread?

Tags: linux, multithreading, signals

In a multi threaded environment what happens when SIGCANCEL is sent to a thread?

What will be the difference in behavior if SIGKILL is sent to a thread?

Comment: I don't think `SIGCANCEL` is supported in Linux at all.  I know that it is deprecated by POSIX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Travis said, `SIGCANCEL` has been [deprecated](http://www.rtsj.org/specjavadoc/javax/realtime/POSIXSignalHandler.html#SIGCANCEL) and doesn't exist in the POSIX standard.

Comment: In the file glibc-2.9/nptl/pthread_cancel.c, i could find SIGCANCEL is used .Hence i was wondering about the functionality. So what exactly happens when you call pthread_cancel() ?

Comment: @notytony Yes, it seems to still exist in glibc 2.9, but if you look at the kernel manpages, [it is not there](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/signal.7.html). I have no experience with pthread, but it seems to not be your standard signal. The little bit of documentation that I read indicates that it is used to send a signal to a thread that is in the same process as the caller. You might want to compare pthread_cancel to [pthread_kill](http://glibc.sourcearchive.com/documentation/2.9-9ubuntu2/pthread__kill_8c-source.html).

Answer (score 2):

The `SIGCANCEL` currently used (internally) in the `glibc` pthread implementation is defined as `__SIGRTMIN`.

If `pthread_cancel()` is called for a thread which has its cancel type set to asynchronous, it is brought down by being sent a `__SIGRTMIN` via `tgkill()`.

In reverse this could mean that a thread receiving `__SIGRTMIN` would behave as if it was cancelled asynchronously. (I did not tested this)